# Cannot add OpenJDK 8 repository in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, java

When i'm trying to add the Openjdk 8 repository with this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa -y
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:openjdk-r/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I have already run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
sudo date --set="2016-5-18 11:24"
```

My virtual machine was not synchronised

Comment: Did not work for me. I tried to set the time through the GUI first on Gnome, then I use the `timedatectl` command to set my timezone because my time was correct, but it was in another timezone. I finally ran this command to the precise second as shown on https://www.timeanddate.com/, but no avail.